# Advantage of Chainlink's VRF over commitment scheme chain

Tags: hash, randomness, chainlink

**News**

Chainlink announced a randomness oracle via VRF: https://blog.chain.link/verifiable-random-functions-vrf-random-number-generation-rng-feature/.

**Question**

What is the advantage of an VRF over a simple 'hash of hash of hash...'. (see e.g. 3.1 in https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=924116) Basically an infinite commitment scheme where each commitment reveal is automatically the commitment for the next value.

**Detailed explanation**

The [commitment scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme) is a way for someone to commit to a secret value without revealing it. This can be done by simply using a one-way hash function, e.g., `keccak256(12)`. The resulting hash can be revealed in a first step, in a follow-up step the actual secrect number, in our case 12, will be revealed. Anyone can verify the correctness of 12 by computatin `keccak256(12)` themselves.

To make this into an oracle, one would create chains of commitments where you start with a random number and then continue computing the hash of the hash.. `keccak256(...(keccak256(12))...)`. You do that let's say a few billion times and you start sending the last value first. Now you are basically forever committed to a series of random numbers which only you will know in advance and the only thing you could do is stop sending. Sounds identical to the VRF approach in that regard:

> The worst case scenario is that the compromised node does not return a response to a request.

Now I'm wondering if there are any advantages from the VRF? Seems like a more complicated approach than the [commitment chain oracle](https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=924116) without any benefits?

Comment: So you want a smart contract to either:
1. Have the seed (in your example 12) hard coded into the smart contract? or
2. Pulled from a single entity (aka, you) and therefore has a single point of failure. If you deploy a smart contract, and you know the seed, now everyone who uses the smart contract has to trust that you don't steal from them, since you can get every commit from there on out.

Comment: @PatrickCollins But you can combine it with multiple entities where each entity has a commitment chain and the result is just XOR between every participant.

Comment: It's still not random. We want provably random, otherwise we have no way of knowing who is a good oracle and who is a bad oracle. If 50% of our oralces were malicious, we'd never know.

Comment: @PatrickCollins Just one honest oracle would be sufficient for no one to know the result ahead of time. But is that a difference then? With the VRF even if all oracles work together, they couldn't know the secret ahead of time?

Comment: I think that's the key right there. I could be wrong, there could be more, the Chainlink team has only just announced it. But putting your faith in one oracle means that your smart contract now has a single point of failure.